# Passing Element to Callback in Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, callback

Is it possible to pass the element that is triggered when an EventListener is activated into the callback function which is triggered?
For example,

`buttonElement.addEventListener("onclick", myCallback(buttonElement) {
}`

`function myCallback(element) {
    // use element
}`

Comment: first, it's `"click"` not `"onclick"` ... second, the argument passed to an event handler is an `Event` object, third, `this` inside an event handler is the element the event handler is added to, and fourth, your syntax is quite wrong ... `buttonElement.addEventListener('click', myCallback);` is what you would do to call `myCallback` function defined as you have, and `use this` inside it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just a small tweak within your code!

Try to write it like this:

```
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myCallback(this);
});

function myCallback(el) {
  alert(el.innerHTML);
}
```

You won't be able to pass the triggered element directly to a function unless you used a helper - dummy - function to be executed, then throw `this` which refers to the current triggered element to your `callback` function.

Hope this helps you out!